# Convert classic asp code to asp.net code in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hi im currently working on asp.net webform project and i want to use the dll of decrypting password from classic asp and to be use in my new project, i only have the dll. 
i cannot add into the reference the dll it say's `A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`

**`Dll name: SamUtils.dll`**

here's the code on classic asp

```
set Cipher = server.createobject("SamUtils.Cipher")
        Cipher.KeyString = Session("UserName")
        Cipher.MainText = RSPassword("Password")
        Cipher.Decrypt
        OldPassword = Cipher.MainText
        set cipher = nothing
```

and here's what i started but i dont know how to continue or im in the correct path

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\projects\WebApps\WebApps\bin\SamUtils.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern void Cipher();
```

**Update code**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Use DllImport to import the Cipher function.
[DllImport("SamUtils.dll")]
public static extern string SamUtilsCipher(string username, string password)
{
     //-- i dont know whats next
}
```

sorry im newbie hope somone help me out with this

Comment: Interop is for interoperability with COM libraries. If your DLL SamUtils is a .NET library, can you add direct reference as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019?

Comment: If the method is declared as external, then you don't need to provide an implementation yourself - that is provided externally (that's why it is `extern`)

Comment: See also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/interoperability-overview)